# azcopy - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: azure

I tried to use azcopy to copy a container of blobs from one Azure account to another:

AzCopy https://account1.blob.core.windows.net/container1/ https://account2.blob.core.windows.net/container1/  /sourcekey:sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss /destkey:ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd /S /Snapshot /V /Y

However, it always fails with error message:
Error parsing source location "https://uatmystory.blob.core.windows.net/uniqueids/": The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

When I open fiddler, I see that it repeatedly creates a tunnel to debugmystory.blob.core.windows.net:443, with body with length 0.

Most weirdly, after I start AzCopy, when I open another browser and try to visit google.com, I get the error message:
The site's security certificate is not trusted!

And it won't let me proceed to google.

The reason seems to be that it changes the proxy settings, so the browser tries to go through a proxy, which is at the loopback address 127.0.0.1. When you stop the browser from trying to go throught he proxy, all is fine again.

Anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling any proxy servers you may have?  That includes Fiddler.

Furthermore, try running AzCopy as an Admin?  Either you have a proxy server screwing up with the SSL trust, or your process does not have access to root authority certificates  needed to validate SSL certs

Comment: I've given up on AzCopy altogether (wrote a solution in PowerShell, which did work). I tried running AzCopy as admin, to no avail. I didn't use proxy servers, so that wasn't an issue.